# Nomenclature won't print

Tags: pdftex, nomenclature, nomencl

I'm trying to implement nomenclature but it doesn't print. I've seen other related situations, but usually that's because they can't execute the command correctly, however, I am using it correctly as an TeXMaker order that says:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.els|
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf
```

and my LaTeX file is the demo one from the `nomencl` manual (but with some very small modifications):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % language modifications

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\title{Nomencl}
\author{Yo}
\date\today

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Main equations}
\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%
\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

The document runs correctly, no errors nor warnings of any kind, but still doesn't print the nomenclature. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry, I've actually find the answer to my own problem, it works when I execute

```
makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg
```

instead.